# Why is to_char left padding with spaces?

Tags: postgresql, cast, number-formatting, string-representation

When ever I use `099` indicating 3 digits 0-padded, I'm getting spaces on the left side.

```
SELECT '>' || to_char(1, '099') || '<';
 ?column? 
----------
 > 001<
(1 row)
```

Why is `to_char` left padding here? Why are there leading spaces?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see that in a simpler test case here

```
SELECT '>' || to_char(1, '0') || '<';
 ?column? 
----------
 > 1<
(1 row)
```

This is because, as @Abelisto said, the space is reserved for the sign glyph,

```
SELECT '>' || to_char(-1, '0') || '<';
 ?column? 
----------
 >-1<
(1 row)
```

You can suppress the sign using `FM`, from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERICMOD-TABLE)

```
Modifier Description Example
FM       prefix      fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks) FM9999
```

So what you want is

```
SELECT '>' || to_char(1, 'FM099') || '<';
```

The zeros aren't suppressed when you demand them with `FM0`

Comment: In addition: it is place for sign, for example `SELECT '>' || to_char(-1, '0') || '<';` does not output space.

Comment: @Abelisto updated with that note